# Dask compute is very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dask, dask-distributed

I have a dataframe that consist of 5 million records. I am trying to process it using below code by leveraging the dask dataframes in python

```
 import dask.dataframe as dd                                          
 dask_df = dd.read_csv(fullPath)
 ............
 for index , row in uniqueURLs.iterrows():
   print(index);
   results = dask_df[dask_df['URL'] == row['URL']]
   count = results.size.compute();
```

But I noticed that dask is very efficient in filtering dataframes BUT NOT in .compute(). So If I removed the line that computes the size of results my program turns to be very fast. Can someone explain this? How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 8):

> But I noticed that dask is very efficient in filtering dataframes BUT
>   NOT in .compute().

You are misunderstanding how `dask.dataframe` works. The line `results = dask_df[dask_df['URL'] == row['URL']]` performs **no computation** on the dataset. It merely stores instructions as to computations which can be triggered at a later point.

All computations are applied only with the line `count = results.size.compute()`. This is entirely expected, as `dask` works lazily.

Think of a generator and a function such as `list` which can exhaust a generator. The generator itself is lazy, but will trigger operations when called by a function. `dask.dataframe` is also lazy, but works smartly by forming an internal "chain" of sequential operations.

You should see [Laziness and Computing](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/user-interfaces.html#laziness-and-computing) from the docs for more information.